# POST/PUT to ASP.Net Core with [FromBody] to a MongoDB GeoJsonObjectModel member is always null

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb

I've been trying to do this:

```
[Authorize, HttpPut("{id}")]
public async Task<bool> Put([FromRoute]string id, [FromBody] GeoData geoData)
{
    // Got the id
    var objId = ObjectId.Parse(id);

    // But the geoData is always null
    // ... remaining code left out for clarity
```

And GeoData the class includes the following:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// The GeoJSON Data
    /// </summary>
    [BsonElement("data")]
    public GeoJsonFeatureCollection<GeoJson3DGeographicCoordinates> Data { get; set; }
```

Calling the PUT using Postman always works, but no data.
This:
[POST request from Angular 2 to ASP.net Core doesn't work. Null value on server side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38974013/post-request-from-angular-2-to-asp-net-core-doesnt-work-null-value-on-server-s)
Wasn't the answer

Answer (score 4):

This little reference pointed me in the right direction to solve the problem:
[Answer to: C# .net core web api post parameter always null](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45940239)
It gave me the clue the the MongoDB GeoJsonObjectModel member may not have a parameterless constructor.

So I changed the code to the following - and now it works:

```
[Authorize, HttpPut("{id}")]
public async Task<bool> Put([FromRoute]string id)
{
    // Got the id
    var objId = ObjectId.Parse(id);

    // And can now get the body also
    GeoData geoData = null;
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(HttpContext.Request.Body, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        geoData = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<GeoData>(reader.ReadToEnd());
    }

    // ...
```